# Sentence Construction when writing an email

Tags: sentence-construction

I want to inform someone that I created a new account for a user. I usually send "A new user account has been created for the user ABC and a welcome e-mail has been sent to the user regarding the same". If I create accounts for multiple users, how can I write this in a better way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not keep the "construction" as it is and just change certain things to plural?

> "New user account**s** **have** been created for user**s** ABC, DEF, GHI, JKL, and MNO, and a welcome e-mail has been sent to **each** user regarding the same."

You could also say

> "New user account**s** **have** been created for 
>   (1) ABC
>   (2) DEF
>   (3) GHI
>
> and a welcome e-mail has been sent to each of them."